# How to make a class a sub folder or collapsible in visual studio

Tags: c#, class, subdirectory

How do you do this in Visual Studio 2010?

It's like a class but collapsible. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Those are "dependent files" as defined in the `.csproj` file. This has nothing to do with classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of extensions in the Visual Studio gallery which state they offer this functionality, e.g:

- [VSCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf)
- [NestIn](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45)

It sounds like NestIn is what you're after, VSCommands lists that it has more features (I have never used it so not in a good position to comment either way)

Comment: I've resorted to nestin :D THanks nkvu

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<DependentUpon>` tag in your `<projectName>.csproj`.

You would have to ***manually*** edit your `<projectName>.csproj` file.

Below is an example: Here `FxTradingInvoice.cs` and `RemittanceInvoice.cs` are added as DependentUpon `Invoice.cs`. This would give the same view as you screeshot in the solution explorer.

***WpfApplication1.csproj :***

```
<Compile Include="Invoice.cs"/>
<Compile Include="FxTradingInvoice.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Invoice.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="RemittanceInvoice.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Invoice.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Hi Jacob - yeah I did check my csproj and yeah it has dependentupon in it. My question is, can you do this graphically? or you have to type it all?

Comment: Thanks! (sad developer is sad)